# SqlException (0x80131904) connecting to mdf database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# app that connects to a SQL Server `.mdf` database file that sits in the root of my apps directory. The app is distributed to other users in a company. They are receiving the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Not all users are getting this error. I am assuming it is a security error. Below is my connection string. Any idea what is causing this issue and how can I resolve it?

```
<add name="EditorConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Resources.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Persist Security Info=true;Connection Timeout=130" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: are you accessing mdf file from remote machine?

Comment: Read the error message. Is SQL Server running on the local machine?

Comment: the app connects to the mdf database which is in the same folder as the app. So yes it is running on the local machine.

Comment: @marc_s I am not sure. Does Sql Express need to be running on the local machine?

Comment: @SLaks Thank you - that makes sense and I feel silly for posting the question :(

Comment: Yes, it must be the **Express** edition, and it must run **locally** on that machine

Comment: @marc_s - make it an answer and I'll check it as the answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the `AttachDbFileName=...` approach in your connection string, the SQL Server used for this **MUST BE** the **Express** edition.

Also, since the connection string contains `.\SQLEXPRESS` as its `Data Source=` value, that SQL Server Express instance **must be running locally** on that particular machine (that's significance of the `.` in the `Data Source=` value)